# Chrome Extension Context Menu not working after update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I have an extension that I recently pushed an update for with updated permissions. Some users are upgrading and reporting that the app doesn't work after the update, in order to make it work again they are having to completely uninstall the app and re-install and everything works as it should.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue? For me in testing everything updated properly, and not everyone is having this issue but it is becoming an issue.

Something to note - the popup tab does work it's just the context menu that has the issue.

**EDIT** - I am unable to replicate and have no clear way to test this beyond getting reports from users. I did notice a drop in reports after deploying another update where I adjusted the order of the permissions... I don't see how this is at all related but I am looking for any clarity as to why this is happening and if there is something that can be done to avoid it in the future.

Comment: Have you already tried to reproduce the bug? If yes, have you also tried to create a reduced test case that shows the bug? Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: What permissions specifically were added/removed/updated?

Comment: @RobW I am unable to reproduce. it's all over the place I added both a startup and oninstall event listener and for me it creates the context menu correctly all of the time. For others it seems to not work at all.

Comment: @wOxxOm the new permission is 'downloads' so you can download directly from the app. I have had this issue come up before for some people but this is happening on a much larger scale... since rollout over 2k people have started reporting it...

Comment: @DrewDahlman You know best what exactly changed. Could you try to simulate what you did (both in API changes, permission changes and update submissions to the CWS).

Comment: @RobW I rolled back and was at one point able to replicate. I then addressed it by changing the listener for creating the context menus. After doing this I cannot replicate. I rolled this change out to the store and had some others update to no success...

Comment: @DrewDahlman Since you're able to reproduce the bug, could you report a bug at https://crbug.com/new? Please attach an extension that shows the bug, and all steps that are needed to reproduce the bug (e.g. install extension, upload update to CWS, update extension, look at console, ...)

Comment: @RobW If I was able to reproduce in a reliable way I would, I am more curious if there are any others that have had similar issues with extensions. Since I cannot reproduce every time or reliably I have no way to file a real bug.

Comment: @Drew A test case helps, even if it is nog 100% reproducible. If you're not comfortable with reporting a bug, then you could edit the question with relevant details. That helps others with finding your question, and it could also help with diagnosing and fixing the issue.

Comment: @RobW I am very well aware of this. Problem is that I have no way to replicate or test against. Hence the reason for the question. I have edited my question.

Comment: @DrewDahlman Even though you're not exactly sure what caused the issue, you did probably record the changes that you made to the extension in version control. And you *also* know how the context menu is called. These bits of information can be used to pinpoint the issue. If you're not sure whether the information that you provided is complete/relevant, you can also include a link to your extension (but not only!). I know some possible reasons, but it's a waste of my and your time to list all options if it's already apparent that the option doesn't apply to your situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating context menu items in a listener for the [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) event. This is the documented and recommended way to create context menu items, but it is not always triggered due to bugs in Chrome ([crbug.com/388231](https://crbug.com/388231), [crbug.com/389631](https://crbug.com/389631), [crbug.com/264963](https://crbug.com/264963)).

I guess that in your case the permission update caused the extension to be disabled, and then `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` was not triggered any more after re-enabling it because of [crbug.com/388231](https://crbug.com/388231).

A work-around for this bug is to use a short timer and try to update the context menu item that should have been created. If the onInstalled event is not triggered, then the context menu is not created and trying to update it will fail. This condition can then be used to ensure that the context menu is created correctly.

```js
var SOME_CONTEXTMENU_ID = "GifMeContextMenu";

function onInstalled() {
    // ... do your thing, e.g. creating a context menu item:
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "title": "GifMe",
        "contexts": ["image"],
        "id": SOME_CONTEXTMENU_ID
    });
}

// Should be triggered whenever the extension or browser is
// reloaded, installed or updated.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInstalled);

setTimeout(function() {
    // This .update() call does not change the context menu if it exists,
    // but sets chrome.runtime.lastError if the menu does not exist.
    chrome.contextMenus.update(SOME_CONTEXTMENU_ID, {}, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            // Assume that crbug.com/388231 occured, manually call the
            // onInstalled handler.
            onInstalled();
        }
    });
}, 222); // <-- Some short timeout.
```